# How to convert an associative array into HTML format

Tags: php, html, arrays

I want to convert the array data into HTML format and want to save the file as a .html file. How can I do this?

Suppose the array is:

```
Array
(
[0-50] => 880
[50-100] => 5
[100-150] => 1
[550-600] => 1
)
```

And I am writting a file like this:

```
<?php
$file = fopen("abc.html","w");
?>
```

I can write this file as a CSV format easily but how can I do this to store a html file from data?

my expected result is -

```
Distance      trips
 0-50          880
 50-100         5
 100-150        1
 550-600        1
```

distance and trips here are the table header and in distance field all are the keys of the array and in trips all are the values of the array.

Comment: What should HTML format be? What is your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use file_put_contents:

```
file_put_contents('path/filename.html', $array);
```

But I'm not sure what you mean with html.

Edit:

```
$html['head'] = '<html><head></head><body>';
$html['content'] = '';
foreach ($array as $entry) {
  $html['content'] .= $entry['whatever'] . "\n";
}

$html['foot'] = '</body>';

file_put_contents('path/filename.html', $html);
```

Comment: i want to store the data in a html format and after that i want to mail that file as an attachment. for that i just have to create a html file from the recieving data,

Comment: So you can build your html and finally save it in a file.

Comment: yeeah it is working , but now i want to show tha data in a tabular format so how can this be done ??

Comment: You mean in a table?

Comment: That's simple html. So you can use $html['content'] .= '<table>'; and so on. Just build it up as you like.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please don't hesitate to upvote and accept the answer ;)

Comment: hello @kiwi juicer , suppose i have created a html format file by doing like above you have told me , but now i want to append the similar type of HTML data in same file . can you please help how can i append the existing file ??

Comment: You can add to the array what ever you like. Importent is the order of the content you add. Not sure what your problem is. Show me your code and what you want to achieve.